# Parse file by splitting string in file and get desired output using single command

Tags: bash, awk, cut

I'm using bash to look into file and parse the results. Can someone tell me how to use cut/awk to split the string and get desired output by using single command? I can get through individual cut and get the below output (with 2 commands and concatenation) but i want to do using single command instead of  two commands.

## test.log:

```
1/98 | (PASSED) com.yahoo.qa.java.projects.stackoverview.questions.Password_01() | 21:20:20
```

## Tried code:

```
str1=`cat test.log | tail -1 | cut -d '|' -f 1`
str2=`cat test.log | tail -1 | cut -d '|' -f 2 | sed -e 's/com.yahoo.qa.java.projects./''/g'`
str3="${str1} | ${str2}"
```

## Expected:

```
1/98 | (PASSED) stackoverview.questions.Password_01
```

Comment: Whats logic behind what data is printed?

Comment: @123 Nothing but parsing to get required value instead of full line to do further required operation.

Comment: Whats the logic though, how are you determining what you want printed...

Comment: Hi Jitesh. I noticed that in a number of your questions, the title is repeated on the first line of the question body. This is unnecessary duplication, and just gives more text for readers to get through. Also, we ask that questions are not chatty here, so there's no need to add thanks, advance thanks, please-help me, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following single `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk 'END{sub(/com\.yahoo\.qa\.java\.projects\./,"",$4);print $1,$2,$3,$4}'  Input_file
```

OR for all kind of `awk`s following may help you in same too.(As per SIR ED's suggestions):

```
awk '{value=$0} END{split(value, a," ");sub(/com.yahoo.qa.java.projects\./,"",a[4]);print a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]}'  Input_file
```

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you sir. Could you please explain more about undefined behavior, sorry I didn't get it/.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Excellent solution!

Comment: @JiteshSojitra, glad that it helped you, keep sharing and keep posting, cheers !!

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you Ed for explaining you are AWESOME sir, I added edit version of it, please let me know if you have any concerns on same.

Comment: Yes that's how to do it but lose the `" "` 3rd arg from split() as you WANT to split using FS so it doesn't make sense to hard-code the value that you hope FS has in a position where it'd use FS by default.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is a simple substitution on an individual line it's better suited to sed than awk and not at all appropriate for cut:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*| [^ ]* \)com\.yahoo\.qa\.java\.projects\.\([^(]*\).*/\1\2/' file
1/98 | (PASSED) stackoverview.questions.Password_01
```

Comment: Great solution!

Comment: Why not just  `\(.*\)com`.

Comment: @123 because that'd fail if `com` appeared later in the string.

Comment: It'd fail anyway if it did, the `.*` right at the beginning is greedy. Maybe you meant `[^|]*` ?

Comment: No, it wouldnt fail anyway. `|` is a literal char in BREs, not a regexp metachar.

Comment: @EdMorton I know, but the entire string after .* could appear elsewhere in the line, although arguing any of this is pointless since OP hasn't specified any resttrictions or logic behind how the string should be extracted...

Comment: Right and I fully expect a followup comment from the OP along the lines of "but my input doesn't REALLY always contain `com.yahoo.qa.java.projects.` ....".

Answer (score 1):

Using **awk**

```
$ awk -F "com[.]yahoo[.]qa[.]java[.]projects[.]" 'sub(/\(\).*/,"",$2)' file
1/98 | (PASSED)  stackoverview.questions.Password_01
```